# how can i store preg match , match into a variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

okay so i wanted to know how can i store preg_match, match into a variable only if the string itself has the matching preg_match.

for example :

```
$string1 = "this is some example id=34 ";
preg_match('/^id=(\d+)/', $string1);
```

i want to store id=34 or id=somenumber into a variable only if $string1 contains id=somenumber
so far i've been playing around with this but so far ive been getting either a true or false/ boolean answer and thats not what i want in this case

Answer (score 3):

[Have you read the docs?](http://php.net/preg_match) They would have told you that `preg_match()` accepts a third argument:

```
preg_match('/^id=(\d+)/', $string1, $matches);
```

Afterwards, `$matches[1]` will contain the matched ID (`'43'`) and `$matches[0]` the whole string that matched (i.e. `'id=34'` in your example).

Comment: Why do you want to store the whole string? If you are going to have multiple values better store them in an array so you can access the actual values easily instead of having to use string functions to split name and value.

Comment: `preg_replace` can perform a replacement using a regex, `preg_replace_callback` lets you call a function that receives the matched value as an argument (and returns the replacement, which could be empty of course).

Comment: no that echos out the whole string i just want to echo out everything but `id=34 `